# Layer stacking rasters in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, multi-band, stack

I have some multi-spectral data, where the individual bands are separate Raster files.

How do I layer stack these rasters so that I get one raster with 3 bands instead of 3 different rasters?

This is quite easy to do in ERDAS and ArcGIS, but I haven't figured out how to do it in QGIS

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I had the same issue some months ago.

Use gdal_merge to generate a new file from the 3 independent rasters.

In OSGeo4W command line you can do this:

```
gdal_merge.bat -separate -of GTiff -o output.tif input1.tif input2.tif input3.tif
```

In QGIS you can do the same with a GUI in the raster plugin "merge" tool.

Comment: I had to enable the GDAL plugin as per Jehtom's answer below to get the Merge menu in the Raster Menu. After that it took hardly a few seconds.

Answer (score 12):

You could try "Raster -> Miscellaneous -> Merge" which is a front-end for GDAL's merge_raster.py. It's part of GdalTools plugin that you may have to enable from the "Plugins ->  Manage plugins..." dialogue.

Answer (score 8):

Geoprocessing was moved to processing toolbar in QGIS 2.16, as you can see below:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For Ubuntu users, just change .bat for .py and quote the files with respective path

Go to the Terminal and write:

> gdal_merge.py -separate -of GTiff -o "path/output.tif" "path/input1.tif" "path/input2.tif" "path/input3.tif"