# Creating Geotiffs MAPIR plugin?

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, qgis-processing, ndvi

I am trying to create Geotiffs on QGIS. I have images(RGB) from a dji phantom 4 pro and images(raw) from a MAPIR ndvi camera. However the two cameras used are not linked.

I wanted to know if you have any tips on how to sync these images pre QGIS combining them into a geotiff for PIX4d?

I currently have more jpgs then mapir raw files.

Also in the MAPIR plugin when creating geotiff what camera should be selected?

Comment: The first thing you need to do is resample one to match the other such that both have the same cell size and origin. JPEG is not a good format for later processing as the pixel values change, can you get the raw images as GeoTIFF either uncompressed or one of the lossless compressions? Then you should be able to 'stack' the images https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22300/layer-stacking-rasters-in-qgis were the images created on the same day at the same time? if not you will get temporal difference problems in your processing even if there's only minutes between scenes.