# What is combine function in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, combine

There is combine function is ArcGIS which combine multiple raster value attributes in one raster layer. I would like to know what's the same process in QGIS?

Comment: Is this what you want to do? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22300/layer-stacking-rasters-in-qgis

Comment: Something like that

Answer (score 1):

It is called "merge", if you want to make a multiband raster (a raster stack) you have to select the option "place each input file into a separeted band".

Comment: Yes I know merge but in that case, the pixels are at the same point.